# Post_save doesn't triggers when instance is changed and saved in Django admin site

Tags: python, django

My goal is to trigger some function, when object is changed via **Django admin site**.

Here is my code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Business)
def segment_biz_promoted_change(sender, **kwargs):
    from lib.segment_analytics import get_segment_api
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if not instance:
        return

    dirty_fields = instance.get_dirty_fields()

    if dirty_fields.get('promoted'):
        segment_api = get_segment_api(instance)
        segment_api.merchant_promoted()
```

This **post_save** works perfectly when I change Business object manually in my code with **.save()**, but it doesn't trigger when I change it via django admin site.

Should I use something else then post_save?

Comment: The `post_save` signal is triggered on any call to `Model.save()`, wherever it happens, and by default the admin __will__ call `Model.save()`, so your problem - if you really have one - is elsewhere.  First thing first: add some logging (or even just a plain `print("hello")`) at the very beginning of your `segment_biz_promoted_change` function and check your devserver's log output. If it doesn't show up when saving from the admin's modelform, then check your admin code for any override that would bypass the `Model.save()` call.

Comment: Django admin uses bulk update not save method.